# Open gnome-terminal from php script

Tags: php, bash, shell-exec

I want to try to open gnome-terminal from php script:

```
shell_exec('bash /data/manager/application/.shell/system.sh');
```

This script use a function to check terminal:

```
SCRIPTCURRENT=`readlink -m $0`
SCRIPTCURRENTPATH=$(dirname "$SCRIPTCURRENT")

runintoterminal () {
    if ! [ -t 1 ]; then
        gnome-terminal -e "bash $1"
        exit 0
    fi
}
runintoterminal $SCRIPTCURRENT
```

I've tried:

```
shell_exec('gnome-terminal');
```

But it's doesn't work... (I know it's possible...) But how to ?

I use nginx and php-fpm. With my own socket. nginx and socket use my user and not www-data. (I'm on ubuntu 14.04LTS)

I've try 0777 rights...

My bash script can run from netbeans IDE ans terminal... but not from php...

Comment: The problem is most likely that gnome-terminal doesn't know where it should draw itself. Normally it shows up on the same display as the program that launched it (IDE, terminal), but web servers don't have displays so it doesn't know where to go. You can try `DISPLAY=:0 gnome-terminal -e "bash $1"` to show it on the current first local graphical login session, if it has permissions for that.

Comment: Great !!! It's work ! DISPLAY=:0 bash /data/manager/application/.shell/system.sh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The problem is most likely that gnome-terminal doesn't know where it should draw itself. Normally it shows up on the same display as the program that launched it (IDE, terminal), but web servers don't have displays so it doesn't know where to go. You can try DISPLAY=:0 gnome-terminal -e "bash $1" to show it on the current first local graphical login session, if it has permissions for that. 
>   ***[that other guy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1899640/that-other-guy)***

```
shell_exec('DISPLAY=:0 bash /data/manager/application/.shell/system.sh');
```

Or on function:

```
SCRIPTCURRENT=`readlink -m $0`
SCRIPTCURRENTPATH=$(dirname "$SCRIPTCURRENT")

runintoterminal () {
    if ! [ -t 1 ]; then
        DISPLAY=:0 gnome-terminal -e "bash $1"
        exit 0
    fi
}
runintoterminal $SCRIPTCURRENT
```