# Cant open Gnome terminal from php

Tags: php, shell

I cant seem to open gnome terminal from php script
tried DISPLAY=:0 did not work
php code:::

```
  <?php 
  shell_exec("/opt/lampp/htdocs/py/test.sh");
  ?>
```

test.sh shell script code

```
#!/bin/sh
gnome-terminal --working-directory=/opt/lampp/htdocs/py -x python3 MaxTemperature.py
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Open gnome-terminal from php script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34142993/open-gnome-terminal-from-php-script)

Comment: i have tired it but does not show me any thing

Comment: when i run 
`DISPLAY=:0 /bin/sh /opt/lampp/htdocs/py/test.sh`
from terminal it work fine but when i run the php file from localhost
`<?php 
shell_exec("DISPLAY=:0 /bin/sh /opt/lampp/htdocs/py/test.sh");
?>`
it does not work

Answer (score -1):

try this one

```
shell_exec('DISPLAY=:0 bash /opt/lampp/htdocs/py/test.sh');
```

system.sh file should be like this

```
SCRIPTCURRENT=`readlink -m $0`
SCRIPTCURRENTPATH=$(dirname "$SCRIPTCURRENT")

    runintoterminal () {
        if ! [ -t 1 ]; then
            DISPLAY=:0 gnome-terminal --working-directory=/opt/lampp/htdocs/py -x python3 MaxTemperature.py
            exit 0
        fi
    }
 runintoterminal $SCRIPTCURRENT
```

Comment: Looking at reference to `system.sh`... Really makes me think you just copied and pasted from the dupe answer I referenced. Please do not do that.